# Concatenate int and string in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using the following code:

```
from c in Country
 where c.IsActive.Equals(true)
 orderby c.CountryName
 select new
 {
     countryIDCode = c.CountryID + "|" + c.TwoDigitCode,
     countryName = c.CountryName
 }
```

But I get this error while running it:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

CountryID is `int` type and TwoDigitCode is `string` type.

How do I concatenate properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this error is preventing you from progressing and is a small dataset you could could hydrate your retrieval from the database by by enumerating the query (call ToList). From that point on, your operations will be against in-memory objects and you may not encounter the error you are receiving.

```
var countries = (from c in Country
where c.IsActive.Equals(true)
orderby c.CountryName
select c).ToList();


var countryCodes = (from c in countries
where c.IsActive.Equals(true)
    orderby c.CountryName
    select new
    {
        countryIDCode = c.CountryID + "|" + c.TwoDigitCode,
        countryName = c.CountryName
    });
```

Comment: I think this answer is outdated and overall bad practice. It's a quick'n'dirty fix which works for now but will bite you later on (e.g. when your currently small dataset suddenly grows, or the client decides he wants the exact same thing on another, much bigger dataset). See flyfisher1952's answer which uses db functions directly, making it a much better way of solving the issue than this answer.

Answer (score 23):

Use System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert

```
 from c in Country
 where c.IsActive.Equals(true)
 orderby c.CountryName
 select new
 {
     countryIDCode = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.CountryID) 
                     + "|" + c.TwoDigitCode,
     countryName = c.CountryName
 }
```

Comment: I'm not really sure. Database types have always acted a bit strangely from my viewpoint and SqlFunctions utilities are what I've used to solve problems like the one posted. I favor this approach over less obvious solutions like the ToList conversion because it **explicitly** shows what you're doing to anyone who comes along maintaining your code.

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer since it solves the issue without introducing performance penalties like Nicholas Murray's answer (even though it does say `...and is a small dataset`).

Comment: In EF6 this was moved to System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.StringConvert

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733085/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-stringconvertsyst

Answer (score 5):

This topic contains a list of CLR methods that can be converted to command tree canonical functions and executed on the server:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx)

For CLR methods not on this list, you would have to pull the results down to the client using .AsEnumerable() and execute a LINQ to Objects query.

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation of the old version of the Entity Framework. I think that with v4 it is solved. For your version the workaround is to convert the result to an enumerable:

```
from a in 
(from c in Country
where c.IsActive.Equals(true)
orderby c.CountryName).AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    countryIDCode = a.CountryID + "|" + a.TwoDigitCode,
    countryName = a.CountryName
}
```

Comment: I am trying your method but i am getting compile time error: 
A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause.

Comment: The query you show will work more or less correctly in both EF 1 and 4.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm not sure is whether you still need this workaround in the v4 or the limitation has been solved.

Comment: Using EF4 and got same error. Found your answer and used AsEnumerable() to resolve it. Really preferring L2S over EF4 right now....

Answer (score 3):

There is no [mapping to a Canonical Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx) for the *int to string casting*.

So just return the *Int* and the *String* in **2 different columns** and then concatenate them in .NET after using the `AsEnumerable` method:

```
var cListTemp = from c in Country
    where c.IsActive.Equals(true)
    orderby c.CountryName
    select new
    {
        countryID = c.CountryID,
        twoDigitCode = c.TwoDigitCode,
        countryName = c.CountryName
    };

var cList = cListTemp.AsEnumerable().Select(c => new {
    countryIDCode = c.countryID + "|" + c.twoDigitCode,
    countryName = c.countryName
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to concatenate strings with the following code:

```
l.StateName + " " + SqlFunctions.StringConvert( (double?)l.Zip ).Trim()
```

It seems like just `SqlFunctions.StringConvert( (double?)l.Zip )` would be good enough, but the resulting string has a bunch of padding on the left, which causes string comparisons to not match. Turns out, `Trim()` works to shave off the extra. I believe `SqlFunctions.StringConvert( (double?)l.Zip ).Trim()` effectively turns into the SQL: `LTrim(RTrim(STR(Zip)))`.

Answer (score -3):

Use `c.CountryId.ToString()` to get a string representation of your CountryId and concatenate that to your TwoDigitCode field:

```
from c in Country
 where c.IsActive.Equals(true)
 orderby c.CountryName
 select new
 {
     countryIDCode = c.CountryID.ToString() + "|" + c.TwoDigitCode,
     countryName = c.CountryName
 }
```

I hope your error actually is a compiler error (can't think of any way the compiler will allow this query. I am not sure how it knows about the Linq to Entities part though).

Comment: No this can't be used. Following error in this case:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: .ToString() and .Format() can not be executed on the sql client so this will give a run time error.

Comment: Works fine in L2S, you're probably using EF. No reason to downvote though, you should have been more explicit.

Answer (score -3):

If you need to concat them together as a string you could use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method:

```
countryIDCode = String.Format("{0}|{1}", c.CountryID, c.TwoDigitCode)
```

Comment: No it gives runtime error:  
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: .ToString() and .Format() can not be executed on the sql client so this will give a run time error.

Comment: Well, the question was 'Concatenate int and string in LINQ' not in Linq To SQL etc. The OP should have been clearer. LINQ != SQL

Comment: The question was also incorrectly tagged by the OP. +1 for answering the question the OP *asked*, even if it wasn't the one he really *wanted.*