# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. I have used this function successfully with previous versions of Entity Framework but I've set up a new project using EF6 and it's not cooperating.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;

e.Result = from n in MyDB.tblBulletins
     where n.AnncStart <= DateTime.Now && n.AnncEnd > DateTime.Now && n.Approved == true
     orderby n.AnncStart descending, n.AnncDate descending
     select new
     {
        n.RecID,
        AnncTitle = n.AnncTitle + " <a href='bulletinAdd.aspx?ID=" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)n.RecID).Trim() + "'><Edit></a>",
        AnncText = (n.AnncImg == null ? n.AnncText : "<a href='images/bulletin/" + n.AnncImg + "'><img src='images/bulletin/" + n.AnncImg + "' class='stickyphoto' alt='Click for larger image'/></a>" + n.AnncText),
        Email = (n.Email == null ? "" : "<br/><a href='mailto:" + n.Email + "'>" + n.Email + "</a>"),
        n.AnncType,
        n.AnncDate,
        n.AnncEnd,
        n.v_EmpBasicInfo.Name
      };
```

When I run this I get
*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

n.RecID is an int primary key on the table in a SQL database (SQL Server Standard Edition)

All I can seem to find through searches is people recommending StringConvert instead of ToString

ADDITION - Stack Trace:

```
[NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.]
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call) +194
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq) +976
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +148
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq) +122
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +148
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq) +87
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +148
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.NewTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, NewExpression linq) +520
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +148
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input) +168
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding) +160
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda) +168
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call) +70
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod) +47
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq) +141
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq) +88
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq) +148
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert() +50
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +563
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a() +83
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +499
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9() +271
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +251
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +600
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +89
System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +416
System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152
System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +40
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +92
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +108
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +19
System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceHelper.ToList(IQueryable query, Type dataObjectType) +225
System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +549
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.GetData() +55
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource) +89
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +61
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind() +105
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.EnsureDataBound() +49
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +15
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

Comment: Is it just my imagination, or are you putting view concerns (HTML code generation) into your data access? That's a bit [smelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: @tim-s I'm not sure how else to do it. What is shown in my datalist is dependent on what data is returned. I'm certainly not a master programmer though so I'd welcome any suggestions.

Comment: @JenniferL not all linq extenstions methods are supported pls see ..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx

Comment: are you using SQL Server as a provider?https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1774

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had the same problem and realized that I was using the wrong type of SqlFunctions. Make sure that you referenced the correct namespace:

```
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
```

and not:

```
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;
```

Comment: same thing, I got this error after upgrading to EF6, and it was working after changing to the correct assembly.

Comment: This must have happened when EF was extracted from the standard .net framework and moved to a separate assembly.  It's unfortunate.

Comment: An what can I do if I'm using MySql?

Comment: Also, ensure that EntityFramework.SqlServer is referenced.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer in this case. Reverting to LINQ to Objects should be the very last resort...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert it to `string`, string concatenation will take care of that.

```
AnncTitle = n.AnncTitle + " <a href='bulletinAdd.aspx?ID=" + n.RecID + "'><Edit></a>",
```

You don't have to call `ToString` as well.

Comment: But the exception says EF doesn't recognize `StringConvert(double? value)`. Why? This method exists solely for exact that usage. What am I missing?

Comment: @pescolino, I am not sure but I would try it calling like `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?)n.RecID)`

Comment: Thanks @pescolino and @Habib! I tried removing StringConvert and got _Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types._ When I add the ? after double I get the original error