# Linq Entity compare 3 fields with wildcard vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, join

Im sure this code was working but cannot rememeber what i did to make it work.

I want to match fields first middle and last with wildcard in between to string user

```
Return (From q In context.users 
        Where (Join( {q.user_first, q.user_middle, q.user_last}, "%"))
            .ToLower.Contains(user.ToLower) 
        Select q).ToList
```

The error message is:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Join(System.String[], System.String)' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

Comment: If "this code was working" why did you have to "make it work"? Anyway, what does it do now?

Comment: sorry i have put the error above.

Comment: Maybe you could also add explanation on what you are trying to achieve with your code. It might result in giving better options to do things than trying to "force your head through brick wall".

Comment: I am doing a phone book lookup, allowing users to type part of the first and/or last name and searching the phonebook database on first, middle and last names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable\`1\[System.Double\])](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733085/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-stringconvertsyst). Different method, but same idea.

Comment: No, it maybe due to me using ef6 as i cannot see a solution to that issue for ef6.

Comment: No. EF just can't convert `String Join` into SQL. This is a very common exception. It *never* worked in EF. *Maybe* you had `context.users.AsEnumerable()`, which turns this into ordinary LINQ to objects. Anyway, you should use three `or` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope someone finds this useful.

I created a computed column in user table called user_fullname:

```
(rtrim((coalesce([user_first]+' ','')+coalesce([user_middle]+' ',''))+coalesce([user_last]+' ','')))
```

The code below, splits the name into an array to work out what to search for.

```
Dim names As String() = user.Trim.Split(" ")
If names.Count = 2 Then
    Dim fname As String = names(0)
    Dim lname As String = " " & names(1)
    Return (From q In context.users Where (q.user_fullname.StartsWith(fname) And q.user_fullname.Contains(lname)) Select q).AsQueryable

ElseIf names.Count = 1 Then
    Return (From q In context.users Where (q.user_fullname.StartsWith(user) Or q.user_last.StartsWith(user)) Select q).AsQueryable

ElseIf names.Count = 3 Then
    Dim fname As String = names(0)
    Dim lname As String = names(2)
    Dim mname As String = names(1)
    Return (From q In context.users Where (q.user_first.StartsWith(fname) And q.user_middle.StartsWith(mname) And q.user_last.StartsWith(lname)) Select q).AsQueryable

Else
    Return Nothing
```