# Linq: How to join tables on keys with different type

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework

I need to write a LINQ query joining two tables tables t1 and t2 on keys which are of different type. 
Table t2's key (KeyB) is string and table t1's key (KeyA) is long.

I am trying the following, but it is giving an exception:

> Method 'System.String StringConvert(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])'
>   has no supported translation to SQL

```
...
join t2 in table2 on SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)t1.KeyA).Trim() equals t2.KeyB
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use `.ToString()` on `t1.KeyA`?

Comment: It is Entity Framework.

Comment: ToString() is not supported in LINQ

Comment: Then ensure you [using right SqlFunctions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22781390/754438)

Comment: Have seen that post. I am connecting to MySQL.

Comment: Try `join t2 in table2 on new {MyKey = t1.KeyA.ToString()} equals new {MyKey = t2.KeyB}`

Comment: That is not working.

Comment: You can't use methods in LINQ to Entities. You can use `ToString()` in normal LINQ @devnull

Comment: All I can find on the subject is to query both and do an in memory join so you can use the `ToString()` method!

Comment: this question seems to be [solved here?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abcdd633-1786-4bbb-8c1f-4f36f32f2b69/linq-join-on-different-types-int-string?forum=linqtosql)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Convert.ToString(Your long value)** and it will be translate to SQL JOIN clause.

```
Table1.Join(Table2, x => Convert.ToString(x.KeyA),  y =>  y.KeyB,
                    (x, y) => new { x,y })
                .ToList()
```